# How to use a vectorised approach in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote the following two functions:

```
def iterate_list(f, x0, n_iterations):

    # initialise the list consisting of iterates of f
    list = [x0]

    # initialise x
    x = x0

    # iterate using for loop
    for n in xrange(n_iterations):
        x = f(x)
        list.append(x)

    # return the list consisting of iterates of f
    return list

def lyapunov_exponent(f, df, x0, n_iterations):

    from iterate_list import iterate_list
    import numpy as np

    # vectorise the list of iterates x0 to xn of f
    vec = np.array(iterate_list(f, x0, n_iterations))

    # calculate the sum of all the values of df for x0 to xn
    s = sum(np.log(abs(df(vec))))

    # calculate the mean as an estimate of the lyapunov exponent
    return s / (n_iterations + 1)
```

and

```
f = k * x * (1-x)
df = k * (1 - 2*x)
```

However now I want to vary the values of `k` in both functions and set up `k = np.linspace(3.0, 4.0, 11)`. How do I amend the function so it will return a list of Lyapunov Exponent for each k value? The difficulty I have right now is that I want to use a vectorised approach instead of a loop.

Comment: Please paste your code **directly** into your question.

Comment: @MarkyPython does it work now?

Comment: @AimeeHe:  No.  You posted a picture of your code.  We can't cut and paste a picture of code into a code editor to run it.  Remove the pictures, and post the code as text.

Comment: @Gerrat Thanks! It should work now:)

Comment: Don't use variable names equivalent to built-ins such as `list` or `dict`. While you have limited the variable to the function scope, you will not be able to currently use the `list` built-in in `iterate_list`

Answer (score 0):

Your functions, run in this context:

```
f = lambda x,k: k * x * (1-x)
df = lambda x,k: k * (1 - 2*x)

# test k iteratively
for k in [1,2]:
    print(iterate_list(f, .25, k, 5))
    print(lyapunov_exponent(f, df, .25, k, 5))

# test k as array; x0 is matching size
k = np.array([1,2])
x0  = np.array([.25,.25])
ll = iterate_list(f, x0, k, 5)
print(ll)
la = np.array(ll)   # turn list array as done in lyapunov
print(la.shape)
print(la[:,0])
print(la[:,1])
print(lyapunov_exponent(f, df, x0, k, 5))
```

produces

```
2243:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack35879467.py 
[0.25, 0.1875, 0.15234375, 0.1291351318359375, 0.11245924956165254, 0.09981216674968249]
-0.383796035676
[0.25, 0.375, 0.46875, 0.498046875, 0.49999237060546875, 0.4999999998835847]
-6.58489821532
[array([ 0.25,  0.25]), array([ 0.1875,  0.375 ]), array([ 0.15234375,  0.46875   ]), array([ 0.12913513,  0.49804688]), array([ 0.11245925,  0.49999237]), array([ 0.09981217,  0.5       ])]
(6, 2)
[ 0.25        0.1875      0.15234375  0.12913513  0.11245925  0.09981217]
[ 0.25        0.375       0.46875     0.49804688  0.49999237  0.5       ]
[-0.38379604 -6.58489822]
```

So running the problem with a vector `k` (and matching `x0`) produces the same results as doing it iteratively.  In fact `k` and `x0` could have almost any dimension (0d, 1d, 2d, etc), as long as they have the same shape.

It may be possible to clean things up, but your functions do 'vectorize' in `k` just fine.

Getting rid of the iteration in `iterate_list` will be trickier, because the values at each stage depends on values in the previous.  It may be possible to write `f(x,k)` to use `cumprod`.

---

Here are the functions from my running script:

```
def iterate_list(f, x0, k, n_iterations):

    # initialise the list consisting of iterates of f
    alist = [x0]

    # initialise x
    x = x0

    # iterate using for loop
    for n in xrange(n_iterations):
        x = f(x,k)
        alist.append(x)

    # return the list consisting of iterates of f
    return alist

def lyapunov_exponent(f, df, x0, k, n_iterations):

    # vectorise the list of iterates x0 to xn of f
    vec = np.array(iterate_list(f, x0, k, n_iterations))

    # calculate the sum of all the values of df for x0 to xn
    s = sum(np.log(abs(df(vec,k))))

    # calculate the mean as an estimate of the lyapunov exponent
    return s / (n_iterations + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I understand the rationale of running with a vector k and matching x0. However, I tried to run your context in python, it kept telling me that "iterate_list takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)", and when I tried to cancel the argument k, it said "lambda() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)". How do I modify my previous functions iterate_list and lyapunov_exponent to eliminate this problem?

Comment: Change the calls of `f` and `df` to include `k`; also add `k` argument to your functions.  `f(x,k)`

Comment: When I posted my answer I tried to remember what changes I'd made to your functions, and couldn't think of any.  But I forget that I'd added `k` as an argument at multiple levels.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I changed the calls of f and df and add argument k to both functions, but it still didn't work. The error message is "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars". So I guess there are still some changes that need to be made in both iterate_list and lyapunov_exponent. I've been trying to figure it out, but I am very new to programming, so it's all pretty hard for me:(

Comment: I pasted in my versions of your functions.